# matplotlib show() doesnt show() in second call

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to display a plot in Jupyter Notebook.
When I call plt.show() the first time everything is fine, but when I call it later on, in a different cell, it doesn't show the plot.
I am using %matplotlib inline.

Cell 1

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Scatter Plot x1, x2")
ax.set_xlabel("x1")
ax.set_ylabel("x2")
ax.scatter(df["x1"], df["x2"], c=df["c"])
plt.show()
```

Cell 2, here i add a new point and want to get the new plot.

```
ax.scatter(center0[0], center0[1], c="red")
plt.show()
```

If i remove the plt.show() statement in the cell 2 i get
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7efd696b9e20>
so the plot is there, but it wont display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to plot again actually, you just need to call your fig

Cell 1:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Scatter Plot x1, x2")
ax.set_xlabel("x1")
ax.set_ylabel("x2")
ax.scatter(df["x1"], df["x2"], c=df["c"])
plt.show()
```

Cell 2:

```
ax.scatter(center0[0], center0[1], c="red")
fig
```

I hope it answers your question